# Can I set multiple cookies for a given Erlang node?

Tags: erlang

To my understanding, if you have two different erlang clusters, each of them using a different Erlang *cookie*, a node belonging to the first cluster will not be able to communicate with a node belonging to the second cluster.

Does Erlang provide a mechanism to allow **multiple** magic cookies for a given node?

Comment: It's not completely impossible to join two such clusters.  You can use [erlang:set_cookie/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#set_cookie-2) to set a separate cookie for each remote node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html) and as mentioned by @legoscia in the comments:

> For a node `Node1` with magic cookie `Cookie` to be able to connect
>   to, or accept a connection from, another node `Node2` with a different
>   cookie `DiffCookie`, the function `erlang:set_cookie(Node2,
>   DiffCookie)` must first be called at `Node1`.

Please note that connections between Erlang nodes are by default *transitive*, meaning that you soon end up with a fully-connected cluster of Erlang nodes, which can heavily affect communication performances. An alternative approach, based on the concept of "group of nodes" is [under research](http://www.release-project.eu/documents/ifl12.pdf).